# Thunderbird default browser configuration

Tags: browser, thunderbird

When I receive a link in an Email, it opens with Chrome, but I want links to open with Firefox.

I found [an article](http://opensource.about.com/od/Internet/a/How-To-Change-The-Default-Browser-In-Thunderbird.htm) on how to solve that, which says to change default application for HTTP / HTTPS links in the attachments tab.

But when I get to the attachments tab, the list is empty : see attached picture

What should I do ? Am I doing wrong ? [image: empty list in the Attachments tab]